# Silverstripe issue: Duplicating Siteconfig/setting menu

Tags: css, silverstripe

I've made a copy of the Settings menu (siteConfig) folder to create a CMS menu for adding company Information.
The Menu functions fine, but the CSS doesn't load correctly.

Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHUJA.jpg

LeftAndMain Extension:
http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/5765ac082c736

Dataobject:
http://www.sspaste.com/paste/show/5765ac3ab26ce

Thanks

-helenclarko

Comment: Is there a reason you chose to replicate the functionality of SiteConfig over extending SiteConfig with your desired fields? The second approach is much easier and requires less code on your part…

Comment: Thanks for your reply Bummzack. I have edited SiteConfig many times in the past and agree that this is by far the easiest way to add a few settings. However, I was looking to learn how to create a new area which doesn't use SiteConfig. This allows me to restrict access to the settings menu for some users, but allow access to this new menu.

Comment: I see, yeah that makes sense. Glad you found a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an alternative solution to this.

SingleObjectAdmin uses a single data object and shows it similar to site config.

https://github.com/Little-Giant/silverstripe-singleobjectadmin